# Using apiKey for huawei push notfications

Tags: push-notification, api-key, huawei-push-notification

i configured apiKey in huawei console for PushKit and i want send push from web app to my android app, so i prepared following CURL:

[image]

[image]

problem is postman still return

```
{"error":"400 Bad Request, body is empty"}
```

when i'm trying to call url from any online curl console result is as following:

```
    {
    "msg": "Authentication Error",
    "code": "80200001"
    }
```

how can i authorize my request by apiKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[image]

---

> `"code": "80200001"`

It's recommended that you check your appid in the URL.

This error code is usually caused by the appid in your URL is different from the appid used to obtain the access_token, or the appid has no permission.

Comment: push kit enabled, app id is valid.
 "or the appid has no permission "- what do you mean?

Comment: hey@Paweł,i updated my answer.Pls kindly refer.You need to use `access_token` for authentication. For details, see the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5?ha_source=hms1). Note that the app ID used to apply for `access_token` must be the same as the app ID used to send messages.

Comment: so i have to get token first and i cant do it as in firebase push? just by api key?

Comment: To use huawei Push, you need to obtain a token. You can send messages in either of the following ways: 1. Send messages through the API or 2. Send messages through the console. This [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/msg-sending-0000001050042119-V5?ha_source=hms1) describes how to send messages on the console.pls refer.

Comment: @Paweł Glad to hear this,and It would be great to upvote my answer if it was helpful to you.  Thanks :)